# Could not initialize class javafx.stage.screen

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to launch 2 javaFX applications, obviously Application#launch() can only be called once per JVM.
After some browsing one told me to manually create a Scene and call Application#start() for the second Application, and so I did:

```
public class Launcher extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("title");
    initLayout();
}

public void initLayout() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Launcher.class.getResource("myFile.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
    this.primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    this.primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

And loading it (from another class) with:

```
    try {
        Application launcher = new Launcher();
        launcher.start(new Stage());
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Though this results in an error saying

```
Exception in thread "Thread_number" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javafx.stage.Screen 
at javafx.stage.Window.<init><Unknown Source>
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init><Unknown Source>
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init><Unknown Source>
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init><Unknown Source>
at classILaunchedFrom.methodLaunchedFrom<Main.java:lineNumber>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, because I'm completely at a loss here. Been cracking my skull far too long with javaFX now.

Comment: don't create the primary stage. it should be created for you by the JavaFX Application Thread.

Comment: @Win.ubuntu that is when you use Application#launch(), but not the way I'm doing it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to completely separate applications? Just make a class that extends stage for your second window and then call it's .show() method from inside the main javafx application thread. Javafx is rather picky when doing things, only one application instance at a time, all work must be done on the same thread and so on.